# Python re capture one match per word

Tags: python, regex

I need to find prices in text document. My code looks like this:

```
sentence = "This is test text $25,000 $25,000$20,000 $30"
pattern = re.compile(ur'[$€£]?\d+([.,]\d+)?', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print pattern.findall(sentence)
```

Desired result is:

```
['$25,000', '$30']
```

I don't need to include $25,000$20,000 in the result becouse this is not valid result for my task. I need only full word matches.

But i get this result:

```
['$25,000', '$25,000', '$20,000', '$30']
```

How to rewrite my regex to include only prices separated by whitespace or punctuation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ur'(?<!\S)[€£$]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?!\S)'
```

I added the negative assertions `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` which mean "fail to match if preceded by a non-space" and "fail to match if followed by a non-space" respectively.

Tested:

```
>>> sentence = "$1234 $56$78.90 This is test text $25,000 $25,000$20,000 $30"
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'(?<!\S)[€£$]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?!\S)', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
>>> print pattern.findall(sentence)
['$1234', '$25,000', '$30']
```

If you want to allow certain non-space characters before or after the match, replace `\S` by `[^\s<chars>]` where `<chars>` are the characters you want to allow. Example:

```
ur'(?<![^\s:])[€£$]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?![^\s,.])'
```

allows the pattern to be preceded by a `:` and followed by `,` or `.`:

```
>>> sentence = "$1234 $56$78.90 This is test text:$25,000. $45. $25,000$20,000 $30"
>>> print pattern.findall(sentence)
['$1234', '$25,000', '$45', '$30']
```

Comment: can you please add .,: as delimiter too ? prices can be surrounded by whitespace or puctuation (.,:). for example: "This is test text.$25,000 " need to return $25,000

Comment: Then it becomes ambiguous! `$25,000$25,000` would produce `000` because it is a sequence of digits preceded by a `,`.

Comment: what if we delete "," from separators ? only "." and ":"

Comment: Still ambiguous...`$34.67$78.90` returns `90` since it is preceded by `.`. Your only way out here is to mandate a currency sigil.

Comment: okay.. what if only one separator ":" ? please.. i need example to start working from... separators are very important.. sorry for being stupid)

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get it (although there are many people with more regex skills than I have):

```
pattern = re.compile(ur'(?:^|\s)[$€£]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?=\s|$)', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print pattern.findall(sentence) # [' $25,000', ' $30']
```

Comment: why is there whitespace in the result ? (?:...) doesn't include group into result.. right ?

Comment: @twoface88 -- sort of.  `(:?...)` means that a new group isn't created.  However, that portion of the match is still included.  The more standard way to do this is to use a lookbehind assertion:  `(?<=...)`, but in python apparently the lookbehind must be a constant length which `(?<=^|\s)` isn't. (it's length 0 or 1), so unfortunately that doesn't work.  post-processing the `findall` is easy though:  `[ x.strip() for x in pattern.findall(sentence)]` will do it.

Comment: what about puntuation ? in case like this: "This is test text.$25,000 " $25,000 isn't found

Comment: I suppose you can just add it to the group in front:  `(?:^|\s|[.,])`, but then it won't get stripped off... blast...